# iphone-UIAlertview-UIIndicatorview

Tags: iphone

i Am New In Iphone development. i have one form in which for display data I am calling a webservice. When that service is called it parses from other file,  And Page Navigates To 'Send Page' In Which These Data Is Displayed In a UITableview.

i am also using uiAtertview And UIIndicatorview Both For Displaying that the process is going. But Problem Is When I Click On  Button I Call UIAtertView + UIIndicator But It Is Not getting Displayed And Data is Also Not getting Displayed,,,

My Code Is

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Configuring Preferences\nPlease Wait.." message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
[alert show];


UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

// Adjust the indicator so it is up a few pixels from the bottom of the alert
indicator.center = CGPointMake(alert.bounds.size.width / 2, alert.bounds.size.height - 50);
[indicator startAnimating];
[alert addSubview:indicator];
[indicator release];

self.ResultPage = [[ResultPage alloc] init];
self.title=@"    Search    ";

// Here My Webservice Is Call From Another ViewController Class And That Class Display Data //InTo UITableVIew

[self.ResultPage GetSearchResult:StrBookId : txtFPrice.text :txtTprice.text];
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: _ResultPage animated:YES];
```

Please Suggest Me....

Thanx

Comment: are you sure the height you setting for the center of Indicator view is correct??

Answer (score 3):

You can add activity indicator in alert view and show that alert view when you call web service.I also do the same when I call webservice. it locks the view so that the user cannot click anything and look wise also seems to be fine and indicating user that something is going in process.

in .h file

```
UIAlertView *progressAlert;
```

in .m file

```
-(void)showAlertMethod

{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool1=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];           
progressAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Uploading please wait...\n" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
    CGRect alertFrame = progressAlert.frame;
    UIActivityIndicatorView* activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(135,alertFrame.size.height+55, alertFrame.size.width,30);
    activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
    activityIndicator.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    [activityIndicator startAnimating]; 
    [progressAlert addSubview:activityIndicator];
    [activityIndicator release];
    [progressAlert show];
    [pool1 release];

}
-(void)dismissAlertMethod
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool2=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
    [progressAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    [pool2 release];
}
```

call the method according to your requirements.
I call the methods in this way:-

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(showAlertMethod) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(dismissAlertMethod) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

Comment: Great way of locking the screen, never tried this, but seems cool...still I doubt how good it is to lock the screen and not letting to do anything...again, I see in the code posted by Neeta,  the alertView is displayed first and then the activityIndicator is being added to it, where I feel might be the problem, still a little detailed code from Neeta's side might help to fix the problem.